# PouchDB quick search promise is not a constructor

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, pouchdb

Using TS with Ionic 2, I installed pouchdb-quick-search

```
npm install pouchdb-quick-search
```

Used the plugin, the same way I did with pouchdb-find (which works perfectly fine)

```
import PouchDB from 'pouchdb';
import PouchDBFind from 'pouchdb-find';
import PouchDBQuickSearch from 'pouchdb-quick-search';

/*
...
*/

PouchDB.plugin(PouchDBFind);
PouchDB.plugin(PouchDBQuickSearch);
```

And finally, used the search method the same way as nicely explained in quick-search's READ ME.

```
this.db.search({
  query: searchString,
  fields: ['field_1',
  'field_2',
  'field_3']
}).then(function (res){
  console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
  return true; //temporary
}).catch(...)
```

Yet, as this method is called, I get the error :

```
Promise is not a constructor
```

I was thinking that quick-search would be more efficient than find in that case.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Did you resolve the issue? It's nothing to do with your code but something to do with the latest pouchdb

Comment: I was using it only for a small part. I just gave up on it.